# Ruby: simplest way to convert an array to a hash with named keys?

Tags: ruby

I have some code in a view script that iterates through an array of arrays:

```
<% @rows.each do |data| %>
  <%= data[0] %>: <%= data[1] %><br>
<% end %>
```

How can I easily convert each `data` array to a hash so that I can refer to each item with a key?

```
<%= data[:name] %>: <%= data[:email] %><br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the arrays with named values like this:

```
<% @rows.each do |name,email| %>
  <%= name %>: <%= email %><br />
<% end %>
```

This assumes that every member of the `@rows` array will be the expected two-value array.

Comment: This is cool, but I don't understand how this is possible. A single argument assumes the entire array, but using multiple arguments magically splits that array into arguments? What happens if its a one item array?

Comment: You can also use splat notation to take care of the remaining members of an array, as in `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]].each {|x,*args| puts "#{x} #{args.join(".")}" }` (run this to see what happens). You can also refer to nested arrays such as `[1,[2,3]]` as `|x,(y,z)|`. I'll see if I can find a comprehensive explanation of how this works.

Comment: I did not know about the nested array with parenthesis syntax. Awesome!

Comment: This is also quite useful for deconstructing hashes, like `{ key1: [a, b], key2: [c, d]}.each {|key,(x,y)| ... }`

Answer (score 2):

@Zach's answer is ok, but answering strictly what you asked for, it can be done this way:

```
@rows2 = @rows.map { |row| Hash[[:name, :email].zip(row)] }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Zach and @tokland have supplied two fine answers.  Sometimes it's nice to make first class data objects instead of relying on composition of primitive Hashes and Arrays.  [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) is handy for this:

```
irb> EmailTuple = Struct.new :name, :email
=> EmailTuple
irb> rows = [%w{foo foo@example.com}, %w{bar bar@example.com}]
=> [["foo", "foo@example.com"], ["bar", "bar@example.com"]]
irb> rows2 = rows.map{ |row| EmailTuple[ *row ] }
=> [#<struct EmailTuple name="foo", email="foo@example.com">, #<struct EmailTuple name="bar", email="bar@example.com">]
irb> rows2.map{ |tuple| "#{tuple.name} has email #{tuple.email}" }
=> ["foo has email foo@example.com", "bar has email bar@example.com"]
```